# jquery UI datepicker remove time from date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

I am using [jQuery UI datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) for selecting dates on an input field. Whenever I submit the form, the date is submitted along with timezone info. e.g. 2014-11-02T05:00:00.000Z

Is there a way I can configure the datepicker to only submit the date?

I looked at the api and formatDate just formats the date visually but on form submission, it submits the date along with the timezone info too. I just want to submit the date not the time.

Here is the code snippet:

```
$('#inputDatepicker').datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  formatDate: "mm/dd/yy",
  showOn: "both"
})
```

I looked at a similar question: [Remove Time part out of Jquery UI DatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709171/remove-time-part-out-of-jquery-ui-datepicker) but did not find any satisfactory answer.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to submit the date to the form? Or is it a regular submit button click?

Comment: You can handle it on the server side.

Comment: @dman2306, it is a regular submit button click

Comment: @SaurabhM Can include `html`,  _"submit button click"_ `js` at original post ?

Comment: @SaurabhM `value` of `input` at `change` event appear to be `01/01/0001 ` format ? , as set at `formatDate`:`"mm/dd/yy"` ? Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Here's a reference snippet. I will be updating it more: http://jsfiddle.net/cdmxmkom/2/

Comment: @SaurabhM http://jsfiddle.net/cdmxmkom/3/ . Where is `2014-11-02T05:00:00.000Z` appearing ? At server ?

Comment: Its appearing in the ajax request at server. I think I found the issue: before sending the request, the date is getting converted: new Date(formData.dob).toISOString(). Maybe using .split('T')[0] will solve this issue.

something like 
    new Date('01/02/2015').toISOString().split('T')[0];

Comment: @SaurabhM Does `new Date('01/02/2015').toISOString().split('T')[0];` solve Question ?

Comment: @guest271314, yes it does.